# Phusion Passenger not starting - flock': No locks available @ rb_file_flock - /vagrant/tmp/pids/passenger.3000.pid.lock (Errno::ENOLCK)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, passenger

This is a Rails app that runs on Phusion Passenger.

In development environment(passenger standalone mode) I run it in a Vagrant Ubuntu 14.04 based box in a MBP(at work) and a Linux Mint PC(home).

In gemfile: `gem 'passenger'`

Right now it is at `passenger (5.0.25)` according to my Gemfile.lock.

The command I normally use to start the rails server is `passenger start` which is in a Procfile.

```
rails: passenger start
sidekiq: bundle exec sidekiq
```

In my home PC, when I issue the command `foreman start` or `passenger start` I get:

```
/home/vagrant/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/passenger-5.0.25/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/vendor/daemon_controller/lock_file.rb:67:in `flock': No locks available @ rb_file_flock - /vagrant/tmp/pids/passenger.3000.pid.lock (Errno::ENOLCK)
    from /home/vagrant/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/passenger-5.0.25/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/vendor/daemon_controller/lock_file.rb:67:in `block in exclusive_lock'
    from /home/vagrant/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/passenger-5.0.25/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/vendor/daemon_controller/lock_file.rb:63:in `open'
    from /home/vagrant/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/passenger-5.0.25/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/vendor/daemon_controller/lock_file.rb:63:in `exclusive_lock'
    from /home/vagrant/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/passenger-5.0.25/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/vendor/daemon_controller.rb:219:in `start'
    from /home/vagrant/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/passenger-5.0.25/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/standalone/start_command/nginx_engine.rb:49:in `start_engine_real'
    from /home/vagrant/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/passenger-5.0.25/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/standalone/start_command.rb:322:in `start_engine'
    from /home/vagrant/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/passenger-5.0.25/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/standalone/start_command.rb:63:in `run'
    from /home/vagrant/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/passenger-5.0.25/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/standalone/main.rb:51:in `run!'
    from /home/vagrant/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/passenger-5.0.25/bin/passenger:45:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/vagrant/ruby/bin/passenger:23:in `load'
    from /home/vagrant/ruby/bin/passenger:23:in `<main>'
```

When I use the command `passenger-config restart-app` I get:

```
*** ERROR: Phusion Passenger doesn't seem to be running. If you are sure that it
is running, then the causes of this problem could be one of:

 1. You customized the instance registry directory using Apache's
    PassengerInstanceRegistryDir option, Nginx's
    passenger_instance_registry_dir option, or Phusion Passenger Standalone's
    --instance-registry-dir command line argument. If so, please set the
    environment variable PASSENGER_INSTANCE_REGISTRY_DIR to that directory
    and run this command again.
 2. The instance directory has been removed by an operating system background
    service. Please set a different instance registry directory using Apache's
    PassengerInstanceRegistryDir option, Nginx's passenger_instance_registry_dir
    option, or Phusion Passenger Standalone's --instance-registry-dir command
    line argument.
```

Env var `PASSENGER_INSTANCE_REGISTRY_DIR` is not set, so [following passenger's documentation](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/config/standalone/reference/#--instance-registry-dir-instance_registry_dir) I try to set it doing:

`export PASSENGER_INSTANCE_REGISTRY_DIR=/vagrant/tmp` or `export PASSENGER_INSTANCE_REGISTRY_DIR=tmp`

And then

`sudo -E passenger-status` but with this one I get `sudo: passenger-status: command not found`

As per [Hongli's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31769807/1407371) in another thread with a similar situation, the command `sudo env PASSENGER_INSTANCE_REGISTRY_DIR=/tmp passenger-status` returns:

```
env: passenger-status: No such file or directory
```

Finally, in my rails app tmp folder there are the passenger pid files:

- passenger.3000.pid
- passenger.3000.pid.lock

I'm really clueless. There's no log and everything I've searched and found didn't solve this.

Thanks for helping!

Comment: Could you please try starting passenger in another port and check if the issue still exist.

passenger start -p 3001

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try starting passenger in another port and check if the issue still exist.

passenger start -p 3001

Comment: Same message after `passenger start -p 3001`