# Passenger doesn't seem to be running (Capistrano/Rails/Apache/Ubuntu)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, ubuntu, capistrano, passenger

Deploying a Rails app using Capistrano to an Ubuntu VM running Apache with Passenger enabled.

I followed this tutorial: https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/install/apache/install/oss/trusty/ with a few changes given that I'm on 17.04, not 14.04 LTS.

`passenger-config validate-install` says everything looks fine with both Passenger and Apache. `passenger-memory-stats` shows both Passenger and Apache processes.

I have `sudo apache2ctl restart`ed several times, with no warnings. But `passenger-status`, and therefore the `passenger-config restart-app` that Capistrano runs, reports that Passenger "doesn't seem to be running." So my deploy stops.

There's only one Ruby on the machine, ruby-2.4.1 installed using ruby-install. I have `apt-get update` and `upgrade`d in case of version mismatches.

Apache logs don't show any errors, certainly none related to Passenger.

Why would Passenger internally disagree, saying that it's both configured properly and there are processes running, but then later saying that it's not running?

Comment: There's a 17.04 tutorial here: https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/install/apache/install/oss/zesty/

Comment: What users are you testing with vs running capistrano as? and can you dump the shell env here for both?

Comment: Camden thanks, the steps in the tutorial are the same as far as I can see. Only one user for the moment for both setup and deploy. There's a couple semi-sensitive things in the ENV, but I can give you `PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin`. Nothing in there specifically related to Passenger (like customizing the instance registry directory). Let me know if any other ENV values would help you.

Comment: Is `$TMPDIR` the same in both envs?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question before. I have one remote and one local user. On the server (Ubuntu) `$TMPDIR` is not set. Locally (OSX) it's `/var/folders/50/m8x23f6s7lg6pb2sxpx_47g4m2j3m8/T/`.

Comment: You have to test the commands via ssh on the server, your local osx user environment isn't relevant. When I asked about the users I meant the user capistrano uses and the ssh user you log in as to run commands on the server.

Comment: Ah, okay. Then I didn't misunderstand. Just one remote user, whose `$TMPDIR` is unset. The `PATH` I gave you was remote as well.

Comment: Do you set the `PassengerInstanceRegistryDir`? If so then your CLI tools need the `PASSENGER_INSTANCE_REGISTRY_DIR` env var set to the same value.

Comment: No, I haven't set that value anywhere.

Comment: Then is there a `passenger.randomstring` dir in `/tmp`?

Comment: you might have multiple passenger installations

Comment: Camden, no, that was locally (OSX).

Comment: Saiqul — how would I check? I believe I have only one Ruby on the machine at all.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40611068/centos-error-phusion-passenger-doesnt-seem-to-be-running

Comment: Tony, thanks, I'll try customizing the instance registry directory.

Comment: Tony, that worked. Specifically I did have to do the final step of configuring the environment variable in my passenger settings. If you want to submit that as an answer here, I'd be happy to credit you with the bounty.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I needed to customize the instance registry directory, as suggested by Tony Vincent:

/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/passenger.conf on the server:

```
PassengerInstanceRegistryDir /home/MYUSER/passenger_temp
```

config/deploy/production.rb in the Rails app:

```
set :default_env, { 'PASSENGER_INSTANCE_REGISTRY_DIR' => '/home/MYUSER/passenger_temp' }
```

Comment: I ran into this problem after upgrading my server from Debian Jessie to Debian Stretch (which upgraded Apache). This worked for me to fix it. Thanks!

Comment: I also encountered this problem when installing phusion passenger in Debian Stretch for apache2.  This seems like a defect in Phusion's operating system and server technology specific installation instructions.  This information is necessary to get passenger-status to work properly.

Comment: You are the champion. +100000

Comment: Passenger will complain because the directory given isn't safe.  The fundamental issue here is that systemd sets up private tmp directories, so the actual path to a file that's in /tmp cannot be known ahead of time.  I use method #1 from this writeup on the subject: https://www.pistolfly.com/weblog/en/2016/01/passenger-config-and-passenger-status-result-in-an-error-on-centos7.html
I do not recommend putting Passenger's registry directory in a standard path as shown in this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to harp on this but did you run `passenger-config validate-install` on the ubuntu server (not osx)? Same for `passenger-memory-stats` and `sudo apache2ctl restart`.

Based on `/tmp` not having a `passenger.randomstring` dir, it sounds like you are confusing local and remote commands. `/tmp` is the default location for `PassengerInstanceRegistryDir`s on Ubuntu so if Passenger is running there should be a dir in `/tmp` that starts with `passenger.`.

Comment: No, I just misunderstood whether that was what you were asking. The only thing I'm running locally is `cap production deploy`. `passenger-config validate-install`, `passenger-memory-stats` and `apache2ctl restart` were all run remotely. `ls /tmp` remotely does not give me anything related to passenger.