# Passenger doesn't seem to be running (Capistrano/Rails/Nginx/Ubuntu)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, nginx, ubuntu-14.04, capistrano, passenger

I'm deploying my app in **Ubuntu 14.4**, **Ruby 2.3.3**, **Nginx** and **Passenger**. When I deploy using `capistrano`, I get the error:

```
SSHKit::Command::Failed: passenger-config exit status: 1
passenger-config stdout: Nothing written
passenger-config stderr: *** ERROR: Phusion Passenger doesn't seem to be running. If you are sure that it
is running, then the causes of this problem could be one of:

 1. You customized the instance registry directory using Apache's
    PassengerInstanceRegistryDir option, Nginx's
    passenger_instance_registry_dir option, or Phusion Passenger Standalone's
    --instance-registry-dir command line argument. If so, please set the
    environment variable PASSENGER_INSTANCE_REGISTRY_DIR to that directory
    and run this command again.
 2. The instance directory has been removed by an operating system background
    service. Please set a different instance registry directory using Apache's
    PassengerInstanceRegistryDir option, Nginx's passenger_instance_registry_dir
    option, or Phusion Passenger Standalone's --instance-registry-dir command
    line argument.

Tasks: TOP => passenger:restart
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
The deploy has failed with an error: Exception while executing as user@IP-Address: passenger-config exit status: 1
passenger-config stdout: Nothing written
passenger-config stderr: *** ERROR: Phusion Passenger doesn't seem to be running. If you are sure that it
is running, then the causes of this problem could be one of:

 1. You customized the instance registry directory using Apache's
    PassengerInstanceRegistryDir option, Nginx's
    passenger_instance_registry_dir option, or Phusion Passenger Standalone's
    --instance-registry-dir command line argument. If so, please set the
    environment variable PASSENGER_INSTANCE_REGISTRY_DIR to that directory
    and run this command again.
 2. The instance directory has been removed by an operating system background
    service. Please set a different instance registry directory using Apache's
    PassengerInstanceRegistryDir option, Nginx's passenger_instance_registry_dir
    option, or Phusion Passenger Standalone's --instance-registry-dir command
    line argument.
```

I have tried several suggestions such as: https://www.pistolfly.com/weblog/en/2016/01/passenger-config-and-passenger-status-result-in-an-error-on-centos7.html

[Passenger doesn't seem to be running (Capistrano/Rails/Apache/Ubuntu)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46058728/passenger-doesnt-seem-to-be-running-capistrano-rails-apache-ubuntu)

But nothing helped! I have checked my Nginx default_sites to see if I point to current rails path and everything looks correct.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This issue was fixed by adding `restart.txt` in `my_app_name/current/tmp`:

*It's done in the server:

*`touch my_app_name/current/tmp/restart.txt`

And add:

`set :passenger_restart_with_touch, true` in `deploy.rb`

**UPDATE**

In the newest version of capistrano, this is taken care of by `gem 'capistrano-passenger'` and adding adding `require 'capistrano/passenger'` in your `capfile`