# Rails/Nginx/Passenger ERROR: Phusion Passenger doesn't seem to be running

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger

I was setting up Passenger and Nginx for my Rails App (Mac OS X 10.11).
I used these commands:

```
gem install passenger
rvmsudo passenger-install-nginx-module
```

All these gets installed perfectly.

Added nginx path in `.bash_profile`:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/nginx/sbin/
```

My nginx conf:

```
passenger_root /Users/MyUserName/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5@rails4115/gems/passenger-5.3.4;
passenger_ruby /Users/MyUserName/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5@rails4115/wrappers/ruby;

server {
    listen 443;
    ssl on;
    server_name app1-local.staging.com;
    rails_env development;
    passenger_enabled on;
    root /Users/MyUsername/Desktop/Github/MainApp/public;
    ssl_certificate /opt/nginx/ssl/mainapp.com.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /opt/nginx/ssl/mainapp.com.key;
}

server {
    listen 443;
    ssl on;
    server_name app2-local.staging.com app3-local.staging.com app4-local.staging.com local.staging.com;
    rails_env development;
    passenger_enabled on;
    root /Users/MyUsername/Desktop/Github/MainApp2/public;
    ssl_certificate /opt/nginx/ssl/mainapp.com.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /opt/nginx/ssl/mainapp.com.key;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name app1-local.staging.com;
    rails_env development;
    passenger_enabled on;
    root /Users/MyUsername/Desktop/Github/MainApp/public;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name app2-local.staging.com app3-local.staging.com app4-local.staging.com local.staging.com;
    rails_env development;
    passenger_enabled on;
    root /Users/MyUsername/Desktop/Github/MainApp2/public;
}
```

After this I started nginx: `sudo nginx`, it worked. Now if I visit `local.staging.com`, I get 502 internal server error.

Nginx error logs displays:
`upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream`

If I do `passenger-status`, it outputs:

```
Phusion Passenger is currently not serving any applications.
```

**Note:** on running, `passenger-config validate-install` command, it says `Everything looks good. :-)`

**EDIT**

Output of `sudo passenger-memory-stats`:

-------- Apache processes --------

----------- Nginx processes ------------

### PID    PPID   VMSize     Resident  Name

62366  1      2411.6 MB  1.3 MB    nginx: master process nginx

63016  62366  2411.6 MB  1.5 MB    nginx: worker process

63008  28339  2377.8 MB  0.3 MB    tail -f /opt/nginx/logs/error.log

------ Passenger processes ------

### PID    VMSize     Resident  Name

36415  0.0 MB     0.0 MB    (PassengerAgent)

63010  2416.8 MB  3.3 MB    Passenger watchdog

63014  2417.6 MB  3.3 MB    Passenger ust-router

63602  2457.3 MB  5.7 MB    Passenger core

**EDIT 2**
Now in nginx error.log, getting:

```
Process aborted! signo=SIGSEGV(11), reason=#0, signal sent by PID 0 with UID 0, si_addr=0x0, randomSeed=1534502322
```

And

```
upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream
```

Any help here?

Comment: Well, you're seeing `Everything looks good` this is weird, can you check `sudo passenger-memory-stats` ?

Comment: @KedarnagMukanahallipatna I have added the output of `memory-stats` in Question.

Comment: Have you set [these](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40656207/4160532) ?

Comment: I am not using Apache or Capistrano. But yeah I have added variable in .bash_profile: export PASSENGER_INSTANCE_REGISTRY_DIR=/temp. Mentioned in the question. After adding variable I have used `source ~/.bash_profile` and even restarted terminal.

Comment: @KedarnagMukanahallipatna I have updated the output.